# Why does Magento have two open source releases?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.6

Why is there a 2.1.15 and a 2.2.6? What is the differences between the code sets? Will I have to go to 2.2.X eventually? Is 2.2.6 experimental?

Comment: 2.2.6 is currently the latest stable release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is there a 2.1.15

This version is magento's early release version series of 2.0 & 2.1. this version's directory structure & xml configuration is different from 2.2.x. So it will be maintaining for the store which are using this(2.0.x/2.1.x) version.

> Why 2.2.x is also

2.2.x is the improved version of 2.0.x/2.1.x. where you can get latest updated code, in way of `ui_component` xml code. your `generated` dir on `root` dir. where 2.0/2.1 `generated` are located into `var` directory.

> Will I have to go to 2.2.X eventually?

Yes, it's current stable version.

> Is 2.2.6 experimental?

No, it's a latest stable version of 2.2.x with more bug fixing & other feature optimization like they improved re-indexing time in 2.2.6 compared to other 2.2.x version.

Check magento's official release notes for more detailed [click here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.6CE.html?_ga=2.82954710.1147110339.1540188952-980285970.1539161094).

I hope this answer will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Both magento 2.1.15 and a 2.2.6 are enhancement versions of magento both include some issue fixes like security fixes for vulnerability but magento 2.2.6 is most stable version because it not only fix the new issues but also it include previous fixes so i would suggest you to go for 2.2.6. for more information you can go through the docs of magento please refer below links:

[Magento 2.1.15](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.15CE.html)

[Magento 2.2.6](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.6CE.html)

Hope this help.